# How to use one Gradle precompiled script plugin in another precompiled plugin inside of buildSrc?

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I have the following setup in my `buildSrc` directory:

```
└── buildSrc
    ├── build.gradle.kts
    ├── settings.gradle.kts
    └── src
       └── main
          └── kotlin
             ├── base-kotlin-project-convention.gradle.kts
             └── spring-boot-dependencies-convention.gradle.kts
```

I would like to declare dependency management in `spring-boot-dependencies-convention.gradle.kts`:

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("io.spring.dependency-management")
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom(org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin.SpringBootPlugin.BOM_COORDINATES)
    }
}
```

and then use it in `base-kotlin-project-convention.gradle.kts` like this:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm")
    `spring-boot-dependencies-convention`
}


dependencies {
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter")
    testImplementation("io.kotest:kotest-assertions-core-jvm:5.3.2")
    testImplementation("org.mockito.kotlin:mockito-kotlin:4.0.0")
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
}

java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Unfortunately I receive the following error:

```
> Task :buildSrc:compilePluginsBlocks FAILED
e: /Users/user/Documents/my-project/buildSrc/build/kotlin-dsl/plugins-blocks/extracted/base-kotlin-project-convention.gradle.kts:5:5: Unresolved reference: `spring-boot-dependencies-convention`

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':buildSrc:compilePluginsBlocks'.
> Script compilation error:

    Line 5:     `spring-boot-dependencies-convention`
                ^ Unresolved reference: `spring-boot-dependencies-convention`

  1 error
```

Is it possible to reuse different [so-called precompiled script plugins](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:precompiled_plugins) in another precompiled script plugins?

Would be great, because when I will configure my module, I would like to use a single plugin:

```
plugins {
    `base-kotlin-project-convention`
}
```

instead of 2 and more:

```
plugins {
    `spring-boot-dependencies-convention`
    `base-kotlin-project-convention`
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution in [Gradle docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_convention_plugins.html#applying_other_precompiled_script_plugins). `id(...)` syntax should be used to reference one precompiled build plugin in another. The following change in `base-kotlin-project-convention.gradle.kts` makes it work as expected:

```kotlin
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm")
    // `spring-boot-dependencies-convention`
    id("spring-boot-dependencies-convention")
}
```